# RadioButton in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здраствуйте! Мне нужно чтобы по `RadioButton` выбирать активное поле или наоборот. Я сделал команду, но она почему то не работает. Что я делаю не так?

XAML

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="auto" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <RadioButton GroupName="Butons" x:Name="ActiveLocation" Content="Active" Width="80" Margin="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding ActiveCommand}" >
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Butons" x:Name="InActiveLocation" Content="InActive" Width="80" Margin="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding InActiveCommand}">
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Butons" x:Name="Alee" Width="80" Content="Alle"  Margin="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding AlleCommand}" IsChecked="True">
        </RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>

    <dxg:GridControl Name="GridControl" ItemsSource="{Binding IndustriesCollections}" Grid.Row="2">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns >
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Gewerk" FieldName="NameProduct"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="MwSt" FieldName="CodeVat"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="S13B4" FieldName="Is13B4"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Aktiv" FieldName="IsActive" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView x:Name="TableView" ShowGroupPanel="False" MultiSelectMode="Row"  IsTabStop="False" AllowLeaveFocusOnTab="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

C#

```
private readonly IEnumerable<IIndustries> _locationsIndustries;

public ObservableCollection<IIndustries> IndustriesCollections { get; private set; }
private ObservableCollection<IIndustries> NewCollection;



public IndustriesViewModel()
{
    NewCollection = new ObservableCollection<IIndustries>();


        _locationsIndustries = CommonLocator.ServiceLocator.Get<IIndustriesDao>().GetAll();

    IndustriesCollections = new ObservableCollection<IIndustries>(_locationsIndustries);
}

private DelegateCommand _activeCommand;

public DelegateCommand RemoveCommand { get; set; }

public DelegateCommand ActiveCommand
{
    get { return _activeCommand = new DelegateCommand(Active); }
}
private DelegateCommand InActiveCommand { get; set; }
private DelegateCommand AlleCommand { get; set; }

private void Active()
{
    foreach (var active in CommonLocator.ServiceLocator.Get<IIndustriesDao>().GetAll().Where(x => x.IsActive == true))
    {
        NewCollection.Add(active);
    }

    IndustriesCollections = NewCollection;
}
```

Помогите разобраться, как мне правильно сделать ?

Comment: `return _activeCommand = new DelegateCommand(Active);` А почему вы каждый раз пересоздаёте команду?

Comment: Приведите больше кода. Ваша часть на C# — это code-behind или VM? Как вы выставляете `DataContext`?

Comment: DelegateCommand - Это что за класс? Где взяли/что внутри?

Comment: DelegateCommand вот что в нутри `public class DelegateCommand : DelegateCommand<object>
    {
        public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod);
        public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, bool useCommandManager);
        public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod, bool? useCommandManager = null);
    }`

Comment: «она почему то не работает». Круто. Почему бы вам не поставить breakpoint и не проверить, вызывается ли она вообще? Вам это проверить гораздо проще, чем нам.

Answer (score 1):

просто не задал `clean` и данные оставались на месте

```
    private void Active()
    {
        var activeCollection = new ObservableCollection<IIndustries>();
        foreach (var active in _locationsIndustries.Where(x => x.IsActive == true))
        {
            activeCollection.Add(active);
        }
        DataCollections.Clear();
        activeCollection.ToList().ForEach(x => DataCollections.Add(x));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему DelegateCommand у вас не наследуется от интерфейса ICommand хотя должен если вы собираетесь делать привязку команд к экземплярам этого класса...

Я полагаю вы используете некий MVVM фреймворк поэтому скорее всего ICommand там всё-же где-то реализован. Так что попробуйте ещё раз разобрать мануалы/примеры кода (если это фреймворк или чья-то библиотека)

Если вы этот класс самостоятельно написали-наследуйте класс от необходимого интерфейса и разбирайтесь с тем, что там ещё нужно в классе дописать в связи с этим...

PS: Попробуйте реализовать свойство к которому делаете привязку следующим образом (на примере вашего кода):

```
public ICommand ActiveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_activeCommand == null) 
        {
            _activeCommand = DelegateCommand(Active)
        }
        return _activeCommand;
    }
}
```